# Как использовать self в классах python

Tags: python, python-3.x

мелкий вопрос, но важный для моего понимания.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что self в классах нужно использовать тогда, когда я работаю с важной для класса переменной, если хочу её использовать в разных методах и модифицировать её. А промежуточные переменные в методах класса я могу писать без self ?

Comment: селф-переменные доступны в других функциях класса.Да.

Comment: Если вы задаете переменную класса (в вашей терминологии без self), то в любом экземпляре класса эта переменной будет такой. Наприме в классе "машина" можно задать количество колес - 4. У каждой создаваемой машины теперь будет 4 колеса. А в конструкторе (с self) задаются свойства, которые будут указываться при создании экземпляра класса каждый раз. Например, цвет. Каждый раз, создавая класс вы будете передавать этот цвет. Например, `Car(color='red')`

Comment: https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-self-in-python-a3704319e5f0

Answer (score 4):

Есть два типа переменных в определении класса.

- переменные класса - (без self) они действуют для любого экземпляра класса
- переменные экземпляра класса - (с self) они для каждого экземпляра класса свои

Таких понятий как - "промежуточная переменная", "важная для класса переменная", не существует.